# CalendarView - new activity for every day

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, calendar, calendarview

I need to display new activity for every day in calendar. This is what I've got:

```
calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,int month, int day) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(Calendar.this, NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

It doesn't work properly because it's always the same activity for each day. Is it a way to display new activity for new day?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to Display in  NewActivity? You might want to make NewActivity - A base Template and Populate it with content passed from Calendar. You can pass information using Intent Extras : http://d.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html